# Get domain name from URL in MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, substring, pymongo

I am trying to get the domain name from a URL field. Currently, it is stored in the collection as a URL:`https://google.bing.com/Jumbo-Privacy`. I just need `google.bing.com`.

For URL as `www.google.com`, I just want `google.com`. Is there anyway for me to do that directly when I display the results of the collection?

WHen I add `'domain': {'$arrayElemAt': [ { '$split': ["$url", "/"] }, 2 ] },`

It works and returns  `google.bing.com` for `https://google.bing.com/Jumbo-Privacy`. But still returns the `www` for everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `urlparse` from the [urllib.parse library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = urlparse('https://google.bing.com/Jumbo-Privacy')
print (url.netloc)
```

gives:

```
google.bing.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write some custom code to parse it.

Here is an example:

```js
//Assuming you'll always have https:// infront

const Url = 'https://moodli.org/geo'

//Split thé URL into an array using the forward slash
let urlSplit = Url.split('/');

//Get the domain name
let domian = urlSplit[2]
```

Comment: this is ec6 right? Can we directly do this in Mongodb?

Comment: Yes. It's javascript. And yes, you can do that with mongodb directly. Theoretically, the query you wrote should work.